# css alternating row style in multi level ul

Tags: html, css, xhtml

## What I would like to have:

Imagine a table with alternating row color. This is my overall goal. But for reasons I need to display the data as a tree with n levels. But in terms of design, it still should look like a table with alternating row colors. Basically the best of two worlds.

[image]

## What I achieved

[image]

Since each level has its own ul/li tags, the nth-child selector (nth-child of **parent**) does not solve my problem. As each level in every subtree has its own alternating row styling, colors are clashing with the other levels. Its just not awesome to look at.

### CSS I use:

```
li:nth-child(odd)>div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

## How could I solve this issue with CSS?

For more complex testing I created a more complex tree.

### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/yshk8dbg/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `id` to you root `ul` to make your `css` more precise:

```css
#tree > li:nth-child(2n + 1) > div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tree">
  <li>
    <div>AAAA</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Node 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Node 3</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Node 3</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Node 4</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>BBBB</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>CCCC</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Node 1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Node 3</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: now only the roots are styled and the nodes are not. i would like to have a complete styling for the table (tree).

Comment: @tzanke It's really not very clear. Can you please share a photo of what you mean ?

Comment: i added a image mockup of what i need

Comment: @tzanke So something like that https://jsfiddle.net/nxb5zgo9/ ?

Comment: Looks good, but only in my simple example, with a more complex tree its not working: https://jsfiddle.net/9v4jeaxk/

Comment: @tzanke Well ok so your question is definitively unclear :/ how are we supposed to know that your tree will grow? Please `upvote` this answer for the time